# PHP: Get nth character from end of string

Tags: php, string

I'm sure there must be an easy way to get nth character from the end of string.

For example:

```
$NthChar = get_nth('Hello', 3); // will result in $NthChar='e'
```

Comment: Here is a nice function you could use the same in your case http://www.junnfo.com/extract-nth-character-from-astring-php.html

Comment: Do you really think it is nth characters you want or (n+1)th ( untill you count 0th, 1th .... approach )

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just do this

```
  $rest = substr("abcdef", -3, 1); // returns 'd'
```

Comment: returns `l` from `Hello`

Comment: returns r from world

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
function get_nth($string, $index) {
    return substr($string, strlen($string) - $index - 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

from [substr examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#refsect1-function.substr-examples)

```
// Accessing single characters in a string
// can also be achieved using "square brackets"
```

thus:

```
$str = "isogram";
echo $str[-1]; // m
echo $str[-2]; // a
echo $str[-3]; // r
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function get_nth($string, $offset) {
    $string = strrev($string); //reverse the string
    return $string[$offset];
}

$string = 'Hello';
echo get_nth($string, 3);
```

As $string[3] will give you the 3rd offset of the string, but you want it backwards, you need to string reverse it.

---

Edit:

Despite other answers (posted after mine) are using substring, and it can be a one liner, it is hardly readable to have `substr($string, -2, 1)`, then just reverse the string and output the offset.

Comment: I really don't have an idea. My **+1** to you however.

Comment: @RoyalBg sorry for replying 2yo comment.

_Internally, PHP strings are byte arrays. As a result, accessing or modifying a string using array brackets is **not multi-byte safe**, and should only be done with strings that are in a single-byte encoding such as ISO-8859-1._

as mentioned in [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Aside of being not multi-byte safe it's also not reasonable to create a reverse copy of the string just to get one character from it.
You should have used strlen()-$offset and accessed the proper byte that way and mentioned encoding incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($string, -3);//returns 3rd char from the end of the string
```

Comment: `$string = 'Hello';
echo substr($string, -3);` returns `llo`

Comment: will gives you llo as output if input is Hello